# linux hdf5 build exceptionally noisy -- reasonable?

Tags: hdf5

I recently downloaded the source for HDF5 (hdf5-1.12.1) and am building it on Ubuntu 20.04.  The number of compiler warnings is remarkable ---the messages reference `-Wnull-dereference`, `-stringop-truncation`, `-Wcast-qual`, `-Wstrict-overflow` ....

It's possible my system is configured by default to have more warnings than usual, but even so, I wouldn't expect something with this wide a distribution to fail so many warning checks.  Any thoughts, beyond "don't run with strict checking"?  If anyone is on the source side of HDF5, is this something you are aware of?

Comment: I always download the pre-built binaries from the **The HDF Group**, so don't build from scratch. Have you tried their Linux build? The HDF Group has a support forum where you can post your question. I think they are the most likely to explain the 'noisy' build behavior: [HDF Forum](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/)

Comment: I'm less keen on prebuilt binaries so hoped to build from source.  I can try their forum, thanks.

Comment: Indeed, I found multiple threads, dating back over a decade in at least one case!  I don't get why they would enable such error messages without actually fixing them, but that's apparently how they roll.  https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/unnecessary-compilation-warnings-enabled/1512/4 for example.